# Can we derive a summation counterpart of an integral in general?

Tags: integration, summation

Is there any general or heuristic rule to convert a function or equation involved with integrals to another one with summations?
How can we deal with the case when the Jacobian matrix show up?
I am not asking about the definition of the integral by a summation like the Riemann integral.
Especially, I am curious of how I can derive a discrete version of the logarithmic convolution.

(I am familiar with first-grade college level mathematics, and some of undergraduate-level algebras and complex analysis. I think the following examples may reflect my level in mathematics.)

We have seen some analogies between integrals and summations or between derivatives and differences.
For example, the norm of a function is defined as:
$\sqrt{\int{|f(x)|^2 dx}}$,
whereas the norm of a vector (or sequence) is defined as:
$\sqrt{\sum_{i}{|a(i)|^2}}$.
The Cauchy–Schwarz inequality holds for both continuous cases (integral) and discrete cases (summation);
$|\int{f(x)g(x)dx}|^2 \le \int{|f(x)|^2dx}\int{|g(x)|^2dx}$
and
$(ax+by)^2 \le (a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)$.
Also we sometimes treat differential equations and difference equations similarly.

Comment: Put dollar signs around your TeX code.

Comment: Yes, you can use TeX.